# Azure Service Bus Process Schedule Message before the schedule time

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an API that will call Azure Topic to schedule a message. Is there a way to receive that message before the schedule time? For example in my code below, I schedule a message to azure topic and it will be queue after 60mins/1hr. Is there a way to received that message before 1hr?

```
string queueName = "topic";
var client = new ServiceBusClient("", new ServiceBusClientOptions()
{
    TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
});

// create the sender
ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

// create a message that we can send. UTF-8 encoding is used when providing a string.
ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage($"Hello world cancel 13 {DateTime.Now}");

// add 5 minutes delay

long seq = await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message,
DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60)
);
```

Comment: if you are doing for testing you can kind of do it with Service Bus Explorer or in Azure portal by submitting a copy of the message without the schedule time and then deleting the original.  This is only useful for once in a while scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message sequence number you get back when scheduling is suitable for cancelling but doesn't allow receiving that message earlier. The service doesn't allow early receiving, as anything that gets the messages to get the active messages (not in the future). For this scenario, I would suggest keeping the data in a database and not leveraging the queue as the database.